# I am stuck in the login page after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, login-screen, bug-reporting, restart

so I got this login page without any access after trying to restart due to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, the keyboard and the mouse are not working at all, before this it did worked but the login was impossible, the screen was kind of blinking and returning to the login page, but now nothing, is there any other way to escape from this bug? [image]

Comment: Your description does not seem to describe a *successful* release-upgrade. With so many problems, it might be simpler to preserve your data and then clean-install 20.04.

Comment: How I do that? Do you mean that I should download the new one and try to install via pendrive without deleting my files? In this non successful upgrade I tried without pendrive, I tried directly from the terminal with a command to run the non successful upgrade.

Comment: Is this a laptop or PC? if it is a laptop connect an external keyboard and mouse and report back. If it is a PC - do you have a different keyboard and mouse to try? also if you have previously set up SSH - can you remote in from your LAN on another machine

Comment: @GianLucca yes, I suggest abandon your attempt to fix all of the problems, create a new USB stick, and reinstall Ubuntu. Whether or not you back up your data before reinstalling is up to you. Considering your hard luck so far, I would not trust your data to survive a reinstall, so a backup seems wise to me. If you have the skills to troubleshoot the problems. my advice would be different.

Comment: @user535733 Yep, that's what I did, I didn't have a proper backup of everything lost a bunch of great music and videos that I downloaded since 2019 (damn), but the most important is safely saved in the cloud, just downloaded Ubuntu using my Android and using a USB otg cable I was able to transfer using an application to a pendrive making it bootable, this is not the first time this happens, now I must go get some external hard drive to avoid things like that, thanks guys